# Dynamically Adding a tooltip to static SVG Using D3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg

We have a static SVG image that we are trying to dynamically add tooltips to say, a hover event on a  object within the SVG image using d3.js in the context of an AngularJS application.

The SVG image is a floorplan and is fairly complex, however we've started very small in the POC process. Here is a small representative snippet of one section:

```
<g id="f3s362c12">
  <g>
    <rect x="75.2" y="92.4" pointer-events="visible" fill="none" 
    width="64.7" height="57.8" />
    <polyline fill="none" stroke="#CDDDED" stroke-width="0.5" 
     stroke-miterlimit="10" points="118.4,149.9 140.3,149.9 140.3,92.4
     75.2,92.4 75.2,128.7" />
  </g>
  <g>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 87.8719 144.8836)" fill="#010101" 
     font-family="arial, sans-serif" font-size="13.4182">362.12</text>
  </g>
</g>
```

D3.js is new to us, however from our research, it seems to be capable of doing what we need it to do since it seems to be designed to work with SVG and represent data in the SVG, however all of the examples we have found are of dynamically creating SVG (mainly charts) but not manipulating existing SVG images.

In a nutshell what we need to do is:

1. Find g tags that have id's starting with "f3" as in g id="f3s362c12" above
2. For each rect associated with the g tag, add a tooltip hover event ( possibly a label?)
3. When a user hovers over say g id="f3s362c12" select the rect and grab the corresponding data record for f3s362c12, that I have loaded from a .csv file, IE:

> ({"floor":"3","location":"***f3s362c12***","name":"David
>   Byrne","occ":"Singer","img":"img/davidAvatar.jpg\r"})

4. Add this info to the tooltip/label so when you hover over g id=f3s362c12, you see a tooltip with David Byrne, whose occupation is singer with his avatar image.

I've created a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/6DkqsFjBMhkX2Bx8TWk1?p=preview) that:

1. Loads the SVG in the HTML
2. Loads the .csv file.

The problem we're having is with the d3.js. 
For example, in our [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/6DkqsFjBMhkX2Bx8TWk1?p=preview), in script.js, we do something like this to find our g tags:

```
 var svg = d3.select("#svgFP");
 var allG = svg.selectAll("g").each(function (d,i) {}
```

However, it's at this point that we hit the wall, since we are trying to find a rect on allG using "this" keyword.

```
  if (this.id.indexOf("f3") > -1)
    {
        //1. Add label/div/hover
        //2. Find corresponding record from array object.
        //3. Inject respective name, occupation and image into label/div along with mouseover/mouseout event.
    }
```

We've been using Firebug to try to find properties to use, but it's been quite frustrating and fruitless to say the least, so we thought that there might be one or two d3/angular guru's in SO that might be able to show us the way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. "Not sure why SELECT doesn't work when SVG is set as INCLUDE, but it doesn't" -- cause controller is run before ng-include resolves. 2. "was getting Error: $digest already in progress" you do not need any apply or whatever in $http callback. Just scope.data = response will do.  3. That your 1, 2, 3 plan is nice - have you tried something? Or you want some1 else to do it for u...

Comment: Thanks for those tips.
Our stopping point currently seems to be where we try something like:

this.select("rect");
 
and receive: TypeError: this.select is not a function

Thanks.

Comment: I've made a small amount of progress and was able to fix the issue regarding the include <svg> issue.

We're still stuck on how to implement a tooltip for our solution correctly using D3 using this example: http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/1016860

We created a new Plunk for our updates:

http://plnkr.co/edit/WYeDdp1ulfJRKAlY2gRz?p=preview


The hover toolbar is displaying data, however we're not adding the hover event to the correct <rect> and the hover event is occurring only on what appears to be on the background rect.

Comment: g[id^='f3'] should find matches more efficiently than iterating in javascript

Comment: @RobertLongson exactly what I used in my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem you have in your plunker is your CSV: The first row a CSV has to be the *header*, which defines what each column is. Thus, I modified your CSV to this:

```
floor,location,name,surname,role,image
3,f3s362c12,David ,Byrne,Singer,img/davidAvatar.jpg
3,f3s362c11,Tina,Weymouth,Bassist,img/tinaAvatar.jpg
3,f3s362c2,Jerry,Harrison,Keyboards,img/jerryAvatar.jpg
3,f3s362c1,Chris,Frantz,Drums,img/chrisAvatar.jpg
```

Now comes your actual question.

The best solution for a D3 code would be *binding the data* to the DOM elements (in this case, your SVG). But, since you already have a static SVG, not made with D3 and not having any bound data, here is a solution.

First, select all relevant group elements:

```
var groups = d3.selectAll("g[id^='f3']");
```

And add the `mouseover` code to that selection.

In the `mouseover` code comes the most important part of this solution: we get the ID of the element which the cursor is over...

```
var groupId = this.id
```

... and then, based on this ID, we filter the previously loaded CSV:

```
var thisData = data.filter(function(d) {
    return d.location === groupId
});
```

This is what the above code does: we loaded the CSV in a variable named `data`. That variable is an array of objects, each object having a `location` property (look at the CSV header I created). Then, we compare the `location` of each object (`d.location`) with the ID of the group (groupId).

Now, you have a variable named `thisData`, which you can use to populate your tooltip.

Here is a demo with a *MCVE* version of your code:

```js
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
            .append("div")
            .style("position", "absolute")
            .style("background-color", "gainsboro")
            .style("border", "1px solid black")
            .style("padding", "20px")
            .style("pointer-events", "none")
            .style("font-size", "12px");

        var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text());

        var groups = d3.selectAll("g[id^='f3']");

        groups.on("mousemove", function() {
            var groupId = this.id
            var thisData = data.filter(function(d) {
                return d.location === groupId
            });
            tooltip.html("Name: " + thisData[0].name + " " + thisData[0].surname + "<br>Role: " + thisData[0].role)
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 2) + "px").style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 2) + "px")
                .style("visibility", "visible");
        }).on("mouseout", function() {
            tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
        });
```

```css
pre {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300" height="100%">
    <g id="background">
        <rect x="1.5" y="0.3" fill="#5A8CC9" width="298.7" height="300.4" />
    </g>
    <g id="f3s362c12">
        <g>
            <rect x="75.2" y="92.4" pointer-events="visible" fill="none" width="64.7" height="57.8" />
            <polyline fill="none" stroke="#CDDDED" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="118.4,149.9 140.3,149.9 140.3,92.4
                75.2,92.4 75.2,128.7        " />
        </g>
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 87.8719 144.8836)" fill="#010101" font-family="arial, sans-serif" font-size="13.4182">362.12</text>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g id="f3s362c11">
        <g>
            <rect x="75.2" y="149.9" pointer-events="visible" fill="none" width="64.7" height="57.8" />
            <polyline fill="none" stroke="#CDDDED" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="118.4,207.8 140.3,207.8 140.3,149.9
                75.2,149.9 75.2,186.2       " />
        </g>
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 87.8719 201.6532)" fill="#010101" font-family="arial, sans-serif" font-size="13.4182">362.11</text>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g id="f3s362c2">
        <g>
            <rect x="140.3" y="149.9" pointer-events="visible" fill="none" width="68.8" height="57.8" />
            <polyline fill="none" stroke="#CDDDED" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="208.7,183.5 208.7,149.9 140.3,149.9
                140.3,207.8 185.8,207.8         " />
        </g>
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 163.782 201.6532)" fill="#010101" font-family="arial, sans-serif" font-size="13.4182">362.2</text>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g id="f3s362c1">
        <g>
            <rect x="140.3" y="92.4" pointer-events="visible" fill="none" width="68.8" height="57.8" />
            <polyline fill="none" stroke="#CDDDED" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="208.7,126 208.7,92.4 140.3,92.4
                140.3,149.9 185.8,149.9         " />
        </g>
        <g>
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 163.782 144.8836)" fill="#010101" font-family="arial, sans-serif" font-size="13.4182">362.1</text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
<pre id="csv">floor,location,name,surname,role,image
3,f3s362c12,David ,Byrne,Singer,img/davidAvatar.jpg
3,f3s362c11,Tina,Weymouth,Bassist,img/tinaAvatar.jpg
3,f3s362c2,Jerry,Harrison,Keyboards,img/jerryAvatar.jpg
3,f3s362c1,Chris,Frantz,Drums,img/chrisAvatar.jpg</pre>
```

Summarising, these are the steps:

1. Create a selection to get your mouse events;
2. Load and parse your CSV;
3. When the user hover over a `<g>`, filter your data array according to that `<g>`'s ID;
4. Use the filtered array to create your tooltip's `html`.

PS: in this snippet I'm using a `<pre>` element to store your CSV. I'm only doing this because, unlike a Plunker, I cannot load a CSV using the S.O. snippet.

Comment: Thanks so much!
You mentioned this in your answer and while I was forging ahead to find an answer (and failing miserably) I felt this nagging suspicion that D3 is more geared to data being bound to the SVG and I was heading in the wrong direction, however since we're working on floorplan diagrams that have mostly static floor layouts, the problem is that personnel is continually changing so I think the plan is to keep the SVG and the data separated.  Also, I don't know if you have any recommendations as far as development environments or books on D3. Thanks again!

Comment: You can keep the SVG and the data separated. As long as you have a property value that matches some SVG attribute (id, class, etc), you can filter it and display the filtered information.

Comment: Since I am using this solution in the context of an AngularJS controller, do you have any recommendations on the best way to push the hover events into an Angular directive?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an Angular user.